# Ableton Live 10 specific tracks cut out randomly for a few seconds during playback and also export

Tags: ableton-live

I just had to re-install Ableton 11 and all plugins after a computer crash (reset Windows). I opened my last project in Ableton and three tracks cut out randomly for about 1-2 seconds before coming back  (all are audio tracks with vocals, lots of filters (stock, Ozone, etc)). It only happens to these three tracks with the vocals, the other 10+ tracks are running fine (audio and MIDI). Weirdly, these random drop outs also happen at the exported WAV/MP3 files.

I tried all things I found on Google:

Update and reinstall Ableton (11.0.5 now)
Freeze the audio tracks
Turn off all plugins/filters on the affected tracks.
Edit buffer size (tried 256, 512, 2014, 2096 and maximum buffer size)
I have an i7 processor, 8GB ram, 512GB SSD hard drive (it worked perfectly before so it can't be the hardware).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Deleted all plugins from all tracks and master AND installed ASIO4ALL. Mastered the tracks again and all works fine... Not sure which helped but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and wanted to put the answer on this thread for anyone who searches this question in the future

If changing buffer size, output methods, etc. does not seem to help, check Splice. If you get signed out (which it will often do automatically), anything you're licensing through Splice (Ozone and Neutron, in my case) will naturally be unable to verify itself. To check if this is your problem, open your plugin to see if it complains about being unlicensed. Then, reopen Splice and sign in. This may also apply with other, non-Splice methods of licensing plugins like Ozone.

It is possible that this was the issue here, and that removing Ozone (and the rest of the plugins) from those tracks got rid of the licensing conflicts. I do not know if this is an intended feature of Ozone included in order to make the plugin unusable when the license is removed, or if it is a side effect of its repeated attempts to verify itself, but this was my solution, and I wish you all luck with your troubleshooting.

Good day :)